# iOS 10.1 , a black line appears on the tabbar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was trying to make a custom tabbar，and i did. I was just writing code like this:

`self.tabBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.tabBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_bg"];`

It works well before iOS10，but on iOS10，a black line appears on the tabbar. When i change the code to `self.tabBar.backgroundImage =[UIImage new];`, the black line disappears, but it is not what i want. How can i make the line disappear on iOS10?

Thanks a lot.

[the line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAR5h.png)

[the picture named "tabbar_bg"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcX0h.png)

Answer (score 1):

i think's it's helpful for you

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transparentShadow.png"]];
```

OR

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: thanks ,but the code "[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transparentShadow.png"]];
"also make's the black line appear.